# php code not executing after calling a javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm having some troubles getting a php redirect to execute after a javascript alert is called. The code is below:

```
echo '<script>window.alert("This device is aleady registered to another user");</script>';
header('Location: page.php');
```

After clicking "OK" on the alert, the redirect does not execute. Any thoughts as to how I can get this code working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send headers after your output. Just redirect the user thru javascript all the way instead.

```
echo '<script>window.location.href = "page.php";</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't output anything before calling `header`, not even a single space. You can use header before outputting the script like in the code below

```
header('Location: page.php');
echo '<script>window.alert("This device is aleady registered to another user");</script>';
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is the best you can do use :-

window.location

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
echo '<script>window.alert("This device is aleady registered to another user");
window.location.href = "page.php";
</script>';
```